# When smartband out of memory?

Tags: wear-os, wearables

I have a smart band using [nRF51822](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51822) chipset, they said it has 256kB/128kB flash + 32kB/16kB RAM, that's tiny memory, 2 days sync data is more than 5kB and it keep growing by time. I want to ask what happen if my device is out of memory ? Should I reset it and my data will lost ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To view the memory allocations of your app's profile, use the [Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) component for Android Profiler that will help you identify memory leaks and memory churn that can lead to stutter, freezes, and even app crashes. It shows a realtime graph of your app's memory use, lets you capture a heap dump, force garbage collections, and track allocations.

There's no directly clear the storage for the app but you can just [reset your watch factory settings](https://support.google.com/wearos/answer/6056905) and set it up again.

Comment: It's not Android wear, just a bracelet